# Including <HTML> tag in output from R2HTML (or any other package) in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way for R2HTML (or any other package) to output my data.frames in HTML tables enclosed within a `<HTML>` `<\HTML>` tags. Currently, the function `HTML(..)` from R2HTML is just exporting only the HTML code for the tables and documentation hasn't mentioned anything about a way to include the tag. Trying to use the `append` argument in `HTML(...)` won't work either, because I'll be running this script everyday.

As for the reasoning behind including the tags, I'm having Windows Task Scheduler run an R script which outputs a .html file, and then I'm having Outlook open it and read it as text so that I can send the output table out via email. However, Outlook only corerctly formats .html files if they contain the HTML tags.

Suggestions or advice would be much welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like this:

`data(iris) # (just to have a data frame)
htmltools::save_html(htmlTable::htmlTable(iris), file = "your_file.html")`

`htmlTable` creates the `<table>...</table>` and `save_html` wraps it with the DOCTYPE and all the formal HTML requirements.

Comment: Thanks! Is `htmlTable` a different package or is this embedded within `R2HTML`?

Comment: You would need to `install.packages(c("htmltools", "htmlTable"))`